# PERMISSION DENIED error while copying database to sdcard .pl

Tags: android, permission-denied

I am trying this for one whole day but i still got this PERMISSION DENIED error after I given WRITE_EXTERNAL STORAGE PERMISSION also.
Now  i tried this program in my phone. Again the same PERMISSION ERROR is on logcat.
i tried with many codes available in this website.It always fails.Guide me with some tuorials for copy database to sdcard

```
try {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

    if (sd.canWrite()) {
        String currentDBPath = "data/com.sri.tut/databases/image_storage.db";
        String backupDBPath = "image_storage.db";
        File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
        File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

        if (currentDB.exists()) {
            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

This is my Logcat output.

```
    09-14 08:36:07.663: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in       Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB      (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:09.413: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:09.963: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:10.203: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:10.654: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:10.854: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:11.083: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:11.283: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:11.683: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:11.934: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:12.224: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:12.463: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:12.734: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:13.053: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:13.413: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:13.694: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:13.914: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:14.303: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:14.563: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:36:14.804: ERROR/Movedb(12336): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:37:42.253: WARN/PackageManager(67): Mounting container com.sri.copydata-1
    09-14 08:37:45.634: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 12336 uid 10053




    09-14 08:37:52.463: WARN/PackageManager(67): Code path for pkg : com.sri.copydata changing from /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-2/pkg.apk to /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-1/pkg.apk
    09-14 08:37:52.463: WARN/PackageManager(67): Resource path for pkg : com.sri.copydata changing from /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-2/pkg.apk to /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-1/pkg.apk
    09-14 08:38:00.773: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(67): no available voice recognition services found
    09-14 08:42:05.613: WARN/PackageManager(67): Mounting container com.sri.copydata-2
    09-14 08:42:11.294: WARN/InputManagerService(67): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 13273 uid 10053
    09-14 08:42:20.063: WARN/PackageManager(67): Code path for pkg : com.sri.copydata changing from /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-1/pkg.apk to /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-2/pkg.apk
    09-14 08:42:20.063: WARN/PackageManager(67): Resource path for pkg : com.sri.copydata changing from /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-1/pkg.apk to /mnt/asec/com.sri.copydata-2/pkg.ap
    09-14 08:42:29.033: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(67): no available voice recognition services found
    09-14 08:42:51.374: ERROR/Movedb(14575): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
    09-14 08:43:14.043: ERROR/Movedb(14575): Error in Copyingjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB (Permission denied)
```

Comment: There is no error in logcat,i am getting this error in my emulator only

Comment: Did you setup an SD card with your emulator?

Comment: ya I already set the Sdcard in my emulator.

Comment: The emulator has logcat, too. Also provide your Manifest, maybe you have placed the permission wrong.

Comment: what is your operation system?

Comment: I believe it's better to use this method [Context.getDatabasePath(String name)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath%28java.lang.String%29) to get the database path, instead of hardcoding it...

Answer (score 1):

If you connect the device to your pc and enable

```
copy files to/from computer etc...
```

You will not have access to write on the sd card.

Disconnect it from pc and try again or disable copy.

Answer (score 0):

the log says you don't have permission to read data from /data/data/com.sri.tut/databases/image_storage.db, by default this /data directory is a linux system directory, its user and group owner is 'system', not your application, so you don't have the permission.

you can see the detail in adb shell, you will see such properties as below:
`drwxrwx--x system   system            2012-09-14 08:30 data`

Comment: cp /data/data/com.sri.tut/databases/image_storage.db /mnt/sdcard   when i used this command in terminal.it working my database file is copying to my sdcard.but why my program is not working? We have to give any other permission to do this activity?

Comment: sorry, I have just tested your code on emulator of android 4.1, it works well, and I can see the backup db on sdcard.

Comment: but according to your log, it says the file /data/data/com.sri.assign/databases/AssignmentsDB  is not existed, can you check that file and the code?  because in your code, you want to back up image_storage.db.